# Migrate Module and a constant Source file

Tags: 7, migrations

In my Migrate module I have the path of the source file ( it's a CSV ) pointing to a file that exists on my server.  That part works great.  If I upload a file and rename it ( using the file browser module ) so that the uploaded file is the same name as the Migrate source file, I get some odd behavior.

The Migrate Import overview page doesn't complain that the file is missing, but the counts for the number of rows unimported are negative $x where $x is the number of rows imported ( from a previous run ).  So if I had imported 60 rows before, uploaded, and renamed the file, refreshed the import page, I see unimported is now -60.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I run the import as an update it completes successfully, though the Imported and Unimported counts are not quite user friendly.  I've opened up an issue here: https://drupal.org/node/2114463